# Missing images when rendering flatlist

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to add a different image to each key of my flatlist. However, the images aren't being showed on the screen by rendering the items, just the keys. The source of the images is correct, so as the name of the images. Can you find the mistake that I have made?

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  searchText: '',
};
 }

 render() {
//Data can be coming from props or any other source as well
const data = [
  { 
    key: 'Tiago',
    logo: '../assets/athlean_x.png'
  },
  { 
    key: 'Beatriz',
    logo: "euro2020.png"
  },
  { 
    key: 'Ricardo',
    logo: "jamor.png"
  },
  { 
    key: 'Miguel',
    logo: "rock_in_rio.png"
  },
  { 
    key: 'Simão',
    logo: "splash.png"
  },
  { 
    key: 'David',
    logo: "edp_cooljazz.png"
  }
];

const filteredData = this.state.searchText
  ? data.filter(x =>
      x.key.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase())
    )
  : data;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.flatlist}>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <Image 
              style={{width:50, height:50, alignSelf: 'center', borderRadius:300}}
              source={{uri:item.logo}}/> 
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>   
          </View>         
        )}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you saved the images in assets folder you need to do like this

otherwise if you are going to render from https server directly
you should add prefix in front of image names.

Hope this helps you to understand.

Comment: I did save the images on the assets folder. That's why I am not getting why this is wrong

Comment: Sorry the code was removed. you can do like this. <Image source={require('../../assets/${item.logo}')} /> or <Image source={{ uri: 'htt ps://server.com/${item.logo}'}} />

Comment: The first one gives the error "Unable to resolve". The path was already corrected by me though

Comment: then try like this way.
import splash from 'assetspath/splash,png';
<Image source={splash} />

Comment: And you need to use ` instead of ' in the first method.

Comment: I mean it does render the image. But I want every key to have their unique image. If coding through that way, I am giving the same image to each one of them

Comment: And even though it says that the first one is an invalid call

Comment: You need to indicate exact imagery directory path,  if you think, you indicated path exactly and it's not working then please try this way, It's working on my end. 
Change the logo variable like this: '../assets/athlean_x.png', '../assets/euro2020.png' ...